# Letterpress in CSS

Tags: css, text, photoshop

I am trying to create the following effect for use as the styling for the  tag.

[image: Letterpress From Photoshop] This is an example in Photoshop

Is there a way to do this with CSS or is there another way to do it?

The white part is semi-transparent, as is the text fill.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: You can do the white bevel very easily, but not the inside darker, blurred part.

Comment: Maybe it could be done with images?

Comment: Possibly, but then you might as well just put the image with all the effects into the page. It's _nice_ to use CSS over images, but when CSS won't do it, you're still allowed to use a few pixels here and there.

Comment: how would i be able to basically create a colour font with images exported from Photoshop which includes the effects?

Comment: You don't. My point was that it's probably better to use images here. Sorry for not being too clear. In terms of using this as an actual font, I have no idea.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll do some more searching for using images in place of letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: (might need to be adjusted)

```
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
```

And for the white highlights:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px white, -1px -1px #444
```

Again these would need to be adjusted, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: `-box-shadow` only works on the containing element, not each letter.

Answer (score 2):

Css text-shadow currently doesn't have an inset option. You can try emulating it with box shadow though. Try [this link](http://lab.simurai.com/css/carveme/) and hover the text.

Comment: Oh wow. That's great! Shame it only works in Webkit though :-(